# Excel Dynamic Range of Dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, dynamic, dynamic-data

It feels like the 1000 millionth question regarding dynamic ranges, but I have not found a solution to this one.

I am trying to replicate the following with a dynamic range using two formula values:

[image]

The formula is the current calendar week, but twice in order to work as X-axis values for a XY plot chart.

I was not able to replicate it. Neither with `INDIRECT` nor connecting the values using `CONCATENATE` or anything close to it.

It works the way it is shown in the picture, but it's not a dynamic range, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution to the problem is the following:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},WEEKNUM(TODAY()),WEEKNUM(TODAY()))
```